# Android studio proxy setting

Tags: android-studio, jvm

I don't know when  jvm property `socksProxyHost` has been set to 127.0.0.1, and how to reset it to default . Please tell me how to let the warning go.THANKS.

Following is the snapshot:

[image: Serrings]

Answer (score 10):

Just try *Invalidate Caches / Restart* in Menu *File*, it works for me.

If you're using Gradle, maybe you want to check the file under $USER/.gradle/gradle.properties to see weather there are some configurations about proxy.

Answer (score 3):

macOS, I solve this as below:

> System preferences -> network -> Ethernet or wifi -> Advanced -> proxies, uncheck proxy you have enabled before.

Comment: should not change here, this will affect system scope golobally, just fix jvm only is needed

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on android studio mac so i don't really know much about windows side, but as Kevin Liu mentioned just click file on your nav bar on top and look for "***Invalidate Caches / Restart***" it will ask you were you want to restart or Invalidate and Restart you can select either and it should work, but i went with invalidate and restart

Hope this helps,and good luck !